# custom list.phtml template is not used on search result page[magento]

Tags: magento-1.9

Product/category listing page uses my custom template. But when I search products. Results are displayed in default list.phtml template.

How to tell Magento to use my [list.phtml] template for result page too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to **catalogsearch.xml** in your **theme layout** folder.(If xml not found, copy the xml file from **base/default/layout** to your **theme layout** folder).Then

find  `<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">`
find inside

```
 <block type="catalog/product_list" name="search_result_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
```

Replace your template path instead of **catalog/product/list.phtml**

Hope this helps